# PowerShell :: Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Sql.Database.Model.AzureSqlDatabaseModel.DatabaseName

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-sql-database, azure-powershell, azure-sql-server

I wrote a script that allows me to query the whole Azure database park:

```
#$ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
# Connect to Azure
$azureAccount = Connect-AzAccount 
# Get Azure Access Token (we will use this to query the databasees)
#$azureToken = Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl https://database.windows.net
$access_token = (Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl https://database.windows.net).Token
# Queries will be picked up from here
$folderPath = '.\Queries'
# Choose how to format each date ("yyyy-MM-dd") or ("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
$DateTime = (Get-Date).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
# List Azure Sunscriptions
Get-Azsubscription | ForEach-Object -Begin { $a = 1 } -Process {"$a $($_.Name)"; $a++}
$SubscriptionChoice = Read-Host -Prompt "Copy/paste the name of the Subscription that you want to investigate. If more than one separate them by a coma, Type `"All`" if you want to target all of them"
# Iterate into subscriptoins and print names
foreach ($gs in $SubscriptionChoice) {
    Select-Azsubscription -Subscription "$gs" | Out-Null
    Write-Host "Let's browse into Azure Sunscription: " -NoNewline
    Write-Host (Get-AzContext).Subscription.Name -ForegroundColor green
    # Fins all Azure SQL Server
    Get-AzSqlServer | ForEach-Object -Begin { $a = 1 } -Process {"$a $($_.ServerName)"; $a++}
    $SqlServerChoice = Read-Host -Prompt "Copy/paste the name of the SQL Server that you want to investigate. If more than one separate them by a coma, Type `"All`" if you want to target all of them"
    
    if ($SqlServerChoice = "All"){
        $SqlServerChoice = Get-AzSqlServer
        }
    
    Foreach ($server in $SqlServerChoice){
        $DatabaseChoice = Get-AzSqlDatabase -ServerName $server.ServerName -ResourceGroupName $server.ResourceGroupName | Where-Object DatabaseName -NE "master"
        Foreach ($database in $DatabaseChoice){
            (Get-ChildItem $folderPath | sort-object {if (($i = $_.BaseName -as [int])) {$i} else {$_}} ).Foreach{
            Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $server.FullyQualifiedDomainName -Database $database.DatabaseName -AccessToken $access_token -InputFile $psitem.FullName | Export-Csv -Path ".\Results\$psitem.csv" -Append -NoTypeInformation
            write-host "Executing $psitem on $database.DatabaseName"
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

However each time the query is executed against a database the Write-Hosts returns:

```
Executing DTU_to_vCore.sql on Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Sql.Database.Model.AzureSqlDatabaseModel.DatabaseName
```

Here a picture:

[image]

This Write-Hosts comes from the line:

```
write-host "Executing $psitem on $database.DatabaseName"
```

In which you can find the two variables:

- **$psitem** : which is the name of the file that contains the query
- **$database.DatabaseName** : which should be the database name but instead of printing the database name is printing `Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Sql.Database.Model.AzureSqlDatabaseModel.DatabaseName`

Why one of the two variable is not interpreted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to encapsulate your variable property in a subexpression operator `$()`.

```
write-host "Executing $psitem on $($database.DatabaseName)"
```

This is because only simple variables get expanded in an expandable string.

**References**

> Only simple variable references can be directly embedded in an
> expandable string. Variables references using array indexing or member
> access must be enclosed in a subexpression.

Source: [about_Quoting_Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7.2)

**Subexpression operator $( )**

> Returns the result of one or more statements. For a single result,
> returns a scalar. For multiple results, returns an array. Use this
> when you want to use an expression within another expression. For
> example, to embed the results of command in a string expression.

```
PS> "Today is $(Get-Date)"
Today is 12/02/2019 13:15:20

PS> "Folder list: $((dir c:\ -dir).Name -join ', ')"
Folder list: Program Files, Program Files (x86), Users, Windows
```

Source: [about_Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2)