# PowerShell date time not combining strings System.Collections.Hashtable.allshift

Tags: powershell

I am attempting to make a string the contains the bellow hash table object strings and the $today variable and resulting with System.Collections.Hashtable.allshift.

```
$today = (Get-Date).ToString('yyyyMMdd')

$saturday = @{
    allshift = "All_Shifts_Checklist_Saturday.xlsx";
    elements = "Elements_Weekend.xlsx";
    night = "Night_Shift_Saturday.xlsx"
}

Write-Host $today$saturday.allshift

###ACTUAL 20220923System.Collections.Hashtable.allshift
###EXPECTED 20220923All_Shifts_Checklist_Saturday.xlsx
```

Comment: `Write-Host $today$($saturday.allshift)` ... use the subexpression operator

Comment: use parentheses so pwsh resolves what's within them first, `Write-Host $today($saturday.allshift)`

Comment: I actually answered another question regarded exactly that a few hours ago. As per other 2 comments, the subexpression operator is what you need there. This is because only simple variables get expanded in an expandable string. See my answer with references to the doc [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73824211/powershell-microsoft-azure-commands-sql-database-model-azuresqldatabasemodel)

Answer (score 2):

Building on the helpful comments:

- Because argument **`$today$saturday.allshift` is implicitly treated *as if it were enclosed in `"..."`***, the interpolation rules of **[expandable strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings)** apply.
- Inside `"..."` strings, only *stand-alone* variable references are expanded as-is by default, e.g., `$saturday`, and not also *expressions*, which includes *property access*, e.g. `$saturday.allshift`. In the latter case, `$saturday` is expanded *as a whole*, and `.allshift` is printed *verbatim*.

  - **In order to embed *expressions* such as `$saturday.allshift` inside `"..."`, you need `$(...)`, the [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--)**:

    ```bash
    # "..." isn't strictly necessary, but is conceptually clearer.
    Write-Host "$today$($saturday.allshift)"
    ```
  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73824211/powershell-microsoft-azure-commands-sql-database-model-azuresqldatabasemodel) for more information, and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375) for a comprehensive overview of the string-interpolation rules.

---

What makes your example tricky are the **subtleties around how PowerShell decides whether a given command argument is implicitly treated as if it were `"..."`-enclosed**:

A few examples (`Write-Output` is used instead of `Write-Host`, to make it more obvious when a compound token is actually passed as *two* arguments):

```bash
# Argument is treated as an *expression*
# -> 'All_Shifts_Checklist_Saturday.xlsx'
Write-Output $saturday.allshift

# The compound token treats $saturday.allshift as an *expression*,
# and $today therefore becomes a *separate argument*.
# -> 'All_Shifts_Checklist_Saturday.xlsx', '20220923'
Write-Output $saturday.allshift$today

# Your case:
# Because the compound token starts with a stand-alone variable reference
# *followed by additional characters* that do not constitute a property
# access or method call, the whole token is considered a single, expandable
# string:
#  * $today expands as intended
#  * $saturday expands *as a whole* - resulting in just the *type name* of 
#    the hashtable, 'System.Collections.Hashtable' (try `@{}.ToString()`)
#  * and '.allshift' is treated as a literal.
# -> '20220923System.Collections.Hashtable.allshift'
Write-Output $today$saturday.allshift
```

- That is, if a compound token *starts with* a variable-based expression that is a *property access* or *method call*, the expression is recognized as such, and whatever follows becomes *a separate argument*.

  - The **exact rules** are complex; [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41254359/45375) discusses them.
- Therefore, it is **best to form a habit to enclose compound tokens that are meant to be a single string argument in `"..."`**, and use `$(...)` to enclose any embedded *expressions* or commands.